# Rank based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help with a mysql query. The query has to be able to show rank, as in the picture http://s27.postimg.org/loixkzipv/img.png .

If the wins are same, compare against the "diff" column, maintaining list order. Please help with this query. Thank you.

I've tried:

```
 SELECT player, wins, diff, rank 
 FROM (
     SELECT player, wins, diff, 
         @curRank := IF(@prevRank = diff, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank, 
         @incRank := @incRank + 1, 
         @prevRank := diff 
     FROM tmpPoradi p, (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1) r  
     ORDER BY diff 
     DESC) s;
```

But this function only compares diff, and doesn't reference wins. How do I make it take into account wins as well?

Comment: How does your query look so far? What have you tried and why does it not work?

Comment: @knittl - refilled answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following query will get the result you need. First you have to calculate rank in a subquery.I think is much simpler than your approach, you just have to sort your results by wins and diff in descending order (supposing the fields are numbers).Then you just select all the results and change order  to player desc.

```
 SELECT player, wins, diff,rank from
 (
 SELECT player, wins, diff, @winrank := @winrank + 1 AS rank
 from tmpPoradi,(SELECT @winrank := 0) r 
 ORDER BY wins DESC,diff DESC
 )  rt
ORDER BY player
```

Hope I am not missing anything.

Comment: what if the player has the same wins and diff?