# Simulate rank in mysql (without rank) with two conditions

Tags: mysql, ranking, dense-rank

Coming from this answer: [Rank based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613999/rank-based-on-two-columns/26614886#comment95862818_26614886)

I've the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpPoradi 
    (`player` int, `wins` int, `diff` int)
;

INSERT INTO tmpPoradi 
    (`player`, `wins`, `diff`)
VALUES
    (1, 10, 12),
    (2, 8, 2),
    (3, 10, 10),
    (4, 8, 1),
    (5, 8, 7),
    (6, 10, 14),
    (8, 10, 10),
   (7, 12, 3)
;
```

and the desired result must be:

```
+--------+------+------+------+
| player | wins | diff | rank |
+--------+------+------+------+
|      7 |   12 |    3 |    1 |
|      6 |   10 |   14 |    2 |
|      1 |   10 |   12 |    3 |
|      3 |   10 |   10 |    4 |
|      8 |   10 |   10 |    4 |
|      5 |    8 |    7 |    5 |
|      2 |    8 |    2 |    6 |
|      4 |    8 |    1 |    7 |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

The thing is that the original answer returns the row count:

```
 SELECT player, wins, diff,rank from
 (
 SELECT player, wins, diff, @winrank := @winrank + 1 AS rank
 from tmpPoradi,(SELECT @winrank := 0) r 
 ORDER BY wins DESC,diff DESC
 )  rt
ORDER BY rank
```

returns:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  player |  wins |  diff |  rank |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|       7 |    12 |     3 |     1 |
|       6 |    10 |    14 |     2 |
|       1 |    10 |    12 |     3 |
|       3 |    10 |    10 |     4 |
|       8 |    10 |    10 |     5 |
|       5 |     8 |     7 |     6 |
|       2 |     8 |     2 |     7 |
|       4 |     8 |     1 |     8 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

and my attemp with conditions returns the following result: (dont know why)

```
  SELECT player, wins, diff,rank from
 (
 SELECT player, wins, diff, @winrank := IF(wins = diff,@winrank,@winrank + 1) AS rank
 from tmpPoradi,(SELECT @winrank := 0) r 
 ORDER BY wins DESC,diff DESC
 )  rt
ORDER BY rank 


+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  player |  wins |  diff |  rank |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|       7 |    12 |     3 |     1 |
|       6 |    10 |    14 |     2 |
|       3 |    10 |    10 |     3 |
|       8 |    10 |    10 |     3 |
|       1 |    10 |    12 |     3 |
|       5 |     8 |     7 |     4 |
|       2 |     8 |     2 |     5 |
|       4 |     8 |     1 |     6 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

so the question is:

**What I'm doing wrong and how can achieve rank by wins and then if wins are tied, subrank by diff, and then if diff are tied, rank are the same?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any functions in MySQL like dense\_rank() and row\_number() like Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494950/are-there-any-functions-in-mysql-like-dense-rank-and-row-number-like-oracle)

Comment: Note you should read Praveen answer (last answer) in the duplication link..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, im reading the links because yes, other answer doesn't answer the question. Let me see if I can learn something... :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/ICBR75166)**

```
  SELECT player, wins, diff, dense_rank, rank, dense_val, prev_wins, prev_diff
  FROM
     (
         SELECT player, 
                wins,                 
                diff, 
                @dense_rank := IF(wins = @prev_wins and diff = @prev_diff, @dense_rank, @dense_rank + @dense_val ) AS dense_rank,                
                @dense_val  := IF(wins = @prev_wins and diff = @prev_diff, @dense_val + 1 , 1) as dense_val,
                @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,
                @prev_wins := wins as prev_wins,
                @prev_diff := diff as prev_diff

         FROM tmpPoradi,(SELECT @dense_rank := 0, @dense_val := 1, @rank := 0, @prev_wins := 0, @prev_diff := 0) r 
         ORDER BY wins DESC,diff DESC
     )  rt
  ORDER BY rank
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, is nice, but that returns 3 for player 1 also

Comment: I mean, records 4 and 5 must be in the 4° rank

Comment: My mistake, I thought the last one was the desire output.

Comment: No problem, anything helps to understand, and I thank you your time to answer. The last one is my near attempt with error, that even i dont know why is happening, My desire output is the first one.

Comment: What I see now is you only compare `win = diff` ,  but you can have 8 wins and 3 diff and still be same rank, isnt?

Comment: actually not, is like soccer. If wins are equal, compare diff (like goals in favor). If diff and wins are equal, then they are really tied in rank. If not, is better the rank with the team with more goals. In this case, the only real tied are player 3 and 8 (10-10 both) that are in the 4° rank

Comment: Well I already did it using the difficult way. I guess you can simplified from there?

Comment: oooooooooooh you use something like lag to check them!!

Comment: Che claro que soy un genio :)

Comment: I still think you need to compare both. Because if both have 8 wins and both have +3 difference in goals they are also in the same rank. In your query you are saying they need to have +8 difference to be on the same rank

Comment: I update the demo to include that case 8 wins 7 diff. https://rextester.com/JMFA40844

Comment: Thanks! yes and also I found that dense_rank jumps from 4 to 6, player 5 must be in the 5° rank. I'm trying to achieve that right now

Comment: then you need rank() not dense_rank();

Comment: oh! Well I just replaced dense_val + 1 for dense_val, works but i dont know if its well

Comment: Check [here](https://rextester.com/LRMWH81446) Now you have all 3 functions. row_number(), rank() and dense_rank()